# Слитно или через дефис? Лироэпический или лиро-эпический?

Tags: орфография

Ученица 11 класса сдаёт ЕГЭ по литературе, выполняет тренировочные задания в Интернете. Написала ЛИРО-ЭПИЧЕСКИЙ через дефис, но в ответах высветилось ЛИРОЭПИЧЕСКИЙ. Я посмотрела материалы Интернета: немыслимый разброд. Вот здесь  [через дефис](https://literary_criticism.academic.ru/169/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%80), а здесь [слитно](https://lopatin.academic.ru/60495/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Как пишется слово?

Я считаю, что по правилу написания сложных прилагательных - через дефис. Слово образовано от "лирический" и "эпический" - признаки проявляются одновременно и равноправно.

Или проблемное слово образовано от словосочетания "лирический эпос"? Тогда надо писать действительно слитно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

И **[*"Русский орфографический словарь"*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%20*%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x)** (Лопатин и др., **4-е изд.**, М., 2012), и бумажный ***"Орфографический словарь русского языка"*** (Букчина и др., **4-е изд.**) фиксируют дефисное написание:

***лиро-эпический.***

Answer (score 0):

А в словаре "Слитно или раздельно" Букчиной и Калакуцкой (1998) зафиксировано слитное написание слова "лироэпический".

Comment: Поподробнее, пожалуйста. Желательно давать полный ответ, а не реплику в продолжение какого-то разговора.